# how to customize the password reset email in a multiauth system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, passwords, reset

**Objective:**
I have 4 types of users in my app. 
I'm trying to send a different email password reset to each depending type of user.

**Problem:**
Is there any way to do this with the Mailto function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to create four different notifications.

create notifications by using artisan command:

`php artisan make:notification MailResetPasswordNotification`

you'll find these in directory App\Notifications\MailResetPasswordNotification

customize your email body for every model.

and in the respective model override this method

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
  $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
}
```